# Compare the differences between two sets

Tags: python, math, metrics

I want to compare two lists that contain times when data is missing. 
When the time is the same, it means that also the same information is missing. So I want to find out how much of the time is missing, including that times may overlap. I couldn't think of any metric other than modified Jaccard Distance. 
Do you have any ideas on any metric or how to compare those lists?
Below is the format of the lists:

```
File1: [{'start': 2022-10-18 15:00, 'end': 2021-10-18 16:00}, {'start': 2021-10-18 16:00, 'end': 2021-10-18 17:00}, {'start': 2021-10-18 20:00, 'end': 2021-10-18 21:00}]
File2: [{'start': 2021-10-18 14:00, 'end': 2021-10-18 15:00}, {'start': 2021-10-18 16:00, 'end': 2021-10-18 17:00}]
```

Based on the above example I could get something like [3/24, 2/24, 4/24]
This would mean - 3/24 that 3 hours out of a day are missing from File1
2/24 2 hours of a day are missing from File2
4/24 Total of 4 hours are missing from both files (because the gap between 16-17 overlaps)

Comment: Could you provide some examples? For ex, "When the time is the same, it means that also the same information is missing" do you you both _start_ and _end_?

Comment: Hey, sure I added an example to the question